# Is $GL_n(\Bbb(R))$ and $SL_n(\Bbb (R)) $ compact?

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, compactness, linear-groups, general-linear-group

I am very confused as nothing has been mentioned in the question -the metric .Howevere I do have an idea about compactness. Somebody hints (not the full answer)  will be appreciated . I will try to figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that we see them as subspaces of the space of all real $n\times n$ matrices, with any norm whatsoever (for instance, $\|(a_{ij})_{1\leqslant i,j\leqslant n}\|=\sqrt{\sum_{i,j=1}^na_{ij}^{\,2}}$, but it doesn't really matter, since all norms on a finite-dimensional real vector space are equivalent), then neither of them is compact, since both of them are unbounded: consider the matrices of the form $\operatorname{diag}\left(n,\frac1n,1,1\ldots,1\right)$.

Comment: Are compact sets in the set of all $n \times n$ matrices closed. I know that compactness implies closeness and boundedness in $\Bbb {R}^k$

Comment: Yes, and you can use that to prove that $GL(n,\Bbb R)$ is not compact, since it is not closed. But $SL(n,\Bbb R)$ *is* closed, and therefore you deduce nothing in that case.

Comment: In every metric space $X$ holds: compact $implies$ closed and bounded; "$impliedby$" is not true in the case of $\dim X = \infty$